# Get points of path With minimum distance to each other

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i need fixed and stable points of path when user define it's direction in my application.
i use these two ways.
way 1 :

```
for (k = 0; k < legs.length; k++)
    {
        var leg = legs[k];
        var steps = leg.steps;
        for (j=0; j < steps.length; j++)
        {
            var step = steps[j];
            var paths = step.path;
            for (i=0; i < paths.length; i++)
            {
                path = paths[i];
            }
        }
}
```

Way 2:

```
for (var i = 0; len = overview_paths.length; i < len; i++)
    {
        path = result.routes[0].overview_path[i];                    
    }
```

but the problem is that the number of pointed that i get in both are so many and i have process all of them in my app and so my app get slow.
so i need a way to get fixed and stable points of path and also i can set some property like minimum distance of points to each other too ,so that get less points.
i use Google map API 3.
fixed and stable points are millstone and exists in each path that trough it

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve here, but you may want to have a look at this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm

Comment: i used some method like this , but points that achieve were not the same.unless you get all points of first step(contain start point) and for other steps use this algorithm.